# How to write to dictionary using user input and loop and parsing by space?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary that I can serialize into a json file. This is my first time trying this so I am very confused.

I want user input for a patient's first name, last name, age, and gender so the dictionary output would be as follows:

```
 "patients": [
    {
      "first_name": "Jane",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "age": 33,
      "gender": f,
     }
  ]
}
```

I want each user input to be in one line until the loop is broken.
So far I only have:

```
patients = {}

info = input("Enter first name, last name, age, and gender separated by space. Enter stop to stop:")
 
for key, value in patients.items():
    print('first_name: {}, last_name: {}, age: {}, gender: {}'. format(key, value))
```

How can I set my code so that a user can continue inputting info until the loop is broken? How can I make the dictionary output as shown above so that each of the inputs is separated and appear as values to the dictionary keys accordingly? I honestly am not sure where to begin and any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you really want. The top shows that `patients` is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary.

Comment: use `split()` to split the input line at spaces. Then assign each element of the list to the appropriate dictionary key, and append it to the `patients` list.

Comment: I'm not sure how to format my code. I don't want a list of dictionaries, just a single dictionary that will be populated with the user input. I changed patients = dict() to patients = {} so make an empty dictionary instead of a list. I'm not sure how to approach the rest of the problem so take user input in a loop and then populate the dictionary from the user input.

Comment: You show `"patients": [ { ... } ]` That's a list of dictionaries.

Comment: If you want a single dictionary, what should the keys be?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I want the keys to be first_name, last_name, age, and gender and the values would be dictated by the user's input. I'm not sure how to approach this using multiple user inputs.

Comment: But you want multiple patients, don't you?

Comment: "I honestly am not sure where to begin and any help is appreciated!" - welcome to Stack Overflow. You [are expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to figure this out before posting; this is **not a discussion forum** and as such we don't provide a help desk or talk through the problem - it is your responsibility to identify one, specific thing that you don't understand, and concretely ask a question about it. It [is not possible to "help you"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program should do what you need. Have added comments for details of what each line is doing.

```py
import json

# defines a dictionary with a list of patients as value
patients = {"patients": []}

# initializes the info variable
info = ""

# run a loop to capture comma separated values from user until they ask to stop
while (info != "stop"):
    info = input("Enter first name, last name, age, and gender separated by space. Enter stop to stop: ")
    if (info != "stop"):
        # splits the input by comma to form a data list
        data = info.split(",")
        # create a patient entry from the data list, using positions and trims any white spaces, converts age to number
        patient_entry = {"first_name": data[0].strip(" "), "last_name": data[1].strip(" "), "age": int(data[2]), "gender": data[3].strip(" ")}
        # adds the patient entry to the patient dictionary
        patients["patients"].append(patient_entry)


# opens a json file to write to and dumps the dictionary content into the file as json
json_file = open("patients.json", "w")
json.dump(patients, json_file)
```

This code expects that each input line is either the exact word `stop` or that it has four comma separated values in the exact format `string, string, number, string`. If you want to handle varied inputs, input validation such as below will need to be added to the code.

- Check if the length of `data` is four
- Check if the third entry is indeed a number

The content of patients.json will look like below

```json
{
    "patients": [
        {
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "age": 45,
            "gender": "m"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Jane",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "age": 40,
            "gender": "f"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is helpful however, when I run my code, I get the IndexError: list index out of range. How can I resolve this?

Comment: That code expects that each input line has four comma separated values or it should be the exact word `stop`. If you want to support varied inputs, will need to add some input validation in the code - such as to check if the length of `data` is four, and to check if the third entry is indeed a number etc. Can you check if your input is in the exact format `string, string, number, string`

Answer (score -1):

> *"... How can I set my code so that a user can continue inputting info until the loop is broken? ..."*

Place the code within a loop, and utilize a *boolean* variable.

```py
m = {'patients': []}
exit = False
while not exit:
    if (i := input()) == '': exit = True
    else:
        a, b, c, d = i.split()
        if '' in (a, b, c, d): exit = True
        else:
            m['patients'].append([
                {'first_name': a},
                {'last_name': b},
                {'age': int(c)},
                {'gender': d}
            ])
```

Here is the output, formatted.
Slightly different than *JSON*, I know.

```
abc xyz 123 m
xyz abc 321 f

{'patients': 
    [
        [
            {'first_name': 'abc'}, 
            {'last_name': 'xyz'}, 
            {'age': 123}, 
            {'gender': 'm'}
        ], 
        [
            {'first_name': 'xyz'}, 
            {'last_name': 'abc'}, 
            {'age': 321}, 
            {'gender': 'f'}
        ]
    ]
}
```

> *"... How can I make the dictionary output as shown above so that each of the inputs is separated and appear as values to the dictionary keys accordingly? ..."*

You would need to just format the output as *JSON*.

This could be as simple as a *string-format*, or using a *JSON* module.

Answer (score -1):

First, it looks like you want a list with a set of dictionaries inside, so I have update the patients variable to a list.

Second, you can use a while loop to continue prompt for user input. For each entry, you can append the new dictionary to the list.

Last, to print each dictionary on one line, you can loop through the patients list and output each dictionary item.

```
patients = []


add_entry = True


def add_patient():
    patient_dict = {}
    patient_dict["first_name"] = input("Enter first name: ")
    patient_dict["last_name"] = input("Enter last name: ")
    patient_dict["age"] = input("Enter age: ")
    patient_dict["gender"] = input("Enter gender: ")
    patients.append(patient_dict)
    return 0


while add_entry:
    add_patient()
    add_new = input("Enter another patient (y/n): ")
    if add_new == "n":
        add_entry = False


for patient in patients:
    print(patient)
```

The output would look like this:

```
{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe', 'age': '33', 'gender': 'm'}
{'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'age': '21', 'gender': 'f'}
```